# jQuery: Strange behavior in my menubar

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseenter

I'm trying to make a menubar with HTML, CSS and jQuery. It is working, kind of. When i hover over my main-menu, the submenu appears. But, if I try to move my mouse down past the first submenu, it disappears. I'll include my JsFiddle. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
         <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Categories 1</a>
                <ul id="cat1">
                    <li class="first"><a href="#">temp1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">temp3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  font: 12px Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
  text-align: center;
} 

#menu > li{
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.first{
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#cat1 > li{
  display: block;
  width: 150px; height: auto;
  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}

#cat1 > li > a{
  display:block;
  background-color: #0000FF;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#cat1 > li > a').hide();
$('#menu > li > a').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#cat1 > li > a').slideDown('slow').css({display: 'block'});
});

$('#cat1 > li > a').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#cat1 > li > a').slideUp('slow').css({display: 'block'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfN7t/19/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It doesn't fix all the problems, but `#menu li a` should be `#menu > li > a` and `#menu li` should be `#menu > li`. Otherwise, those selectors also match the elements inside `#cat1`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your help, but still, when i choose the second submeny, it disappears. I don't see why

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't fix all the problems. If I had a solution, I would have posted an answer.

Comment: @Barmar Btw, should it also be #cat1 > li > a, or wont that make a difference now that #menu > li > a doesnt affect anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I added some CSS:

```
#menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat1 {
  display:none;
}

#menu a:hover {
    color: #dc692e;
}
```

and simplified the Javascript:

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function(){
    $('#cat1').slideDown('slow');
},function(){
    $('#cat1').stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```